# For loop with factor data

Tags: r

I have two vectors of factor data with equal length. Just for examples sake:

```
observed=c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a")
predicted=c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c")
```

Ultimately, I am trying to generate a classification matrix showing the number of times each factor is correctly predicted. This would look like the following for the example:

```
  name  T F
     a  1 2
     b  1 1
     c  1 1
```

Note that the tables() command doesn't work here because I have 11 different factors, and the output would be 11x11 instead of 11x2. My plan is to create three vectors, and combine them into a data frame.

First, a vector of the unique factor values in the existing vectors. This is simple enough,

```
 names=unique(df$observed)
```

Next, a vector of values showing the number of correct predictions. This is where I am running into trouble. I can get the number of correct predictions for an individual factor like so:

```
correct.a=sum(predicted[which(observed == "a")] == "a")
```

But this is cumbersome to repeat time and time again, and then combine into a vector like

```
correct=c("correct.a", "correct.b", correct.c")
```

Is there a way to use a loop (or other strategy that you can think of) to improve this process?

Also note that the final vector I would create would be something like this:

```
incorrect.a=sum(observed == "a")-correct.a
```

Comment: Wouldn't a hashmap/dictionary help you out? For each key (character), you assign a count value.

Comment: You can use words. The idea here is to count up when encountering the word in the predicted and then count down when encountering the word in the observer. So, predicted=c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c") will end with a map that is: a=2, b=3, c=2. Then, we run observed=c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a"); therefore, a=-1, b=1, and c=0. | If the word doesn't exist, add the word=1 to the map. If the word exists in the map, get the value, increase by one, assign the new values to the word, etc.

Comment: Ah I see. The problem with that though is that just because there are the same number of predicted and observed factors (c in the example) in the vectors doesn't mean that there was any correct predictions. predicted=c("a","b", "a", "b") and observed=c("b","a","b","a") would show a=0, b=0, but there were no correct predictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use `data.table` for explicit clean way to define your results:

```r
library(data.table)
observed=c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a")
predicted=c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c")

dt <- data.table(observed, predicted)

res <- dt[, .(
  T = sum(observed == predicted), 
  F = sum(observed != predicted)), 
  observed
]

res
#   observed T F
# 1:        a 1 2
# 2:        b 1 1
# 3:        c 1 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
t(sapply(split(predicted == observed, observed), table))
#  FALSE TRUE
#a     2    1
#b     1    1
#c     1    1
```

Comment: Interesting, going to have to familiarize myself with some of those commands. This gets me the number of correct predictions, but does not display vertically, and does not show incorrect predictions (the number of correct predictions is displayed below each factor).